# d3 Cumulative Line Chart

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, cumulative-line-chart

I am new to d3 charts and i want to create d3 Cumulative Line Chart with date on x-axis,some values on y-axis and x & y  axis's values should appear on tooltip. Here below is my sample code and [sharing a screen shot for better understand my requirements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOwGI.png):

[index.html file]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style> /* set the CSS */

/*body { font: 12px Arial;}

path { `enter code here`
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}*/

</style>
<body>

<input type='button' onclick="Graph()" value='Generate Chart'>

<div id='chart' style="height:300px"><svg></svg>
</div>

</body>   

<link href="https://cdn.healthscion.com/Zureka/scripts/nv.d3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.healthscion.com/Zureka/scripts/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.healthscion.com/Zureka/scripts/nv.d3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    

    var values = [
                                         [Date.parse("02/09/2016 12:46:45"), 150],
                                         [Date.parse("02/08/2016 12:46:45"), 50],
                                         [Date.parse("02/07/2016 12:46:45"), 130],
                                         [Date.parse("02/06/2016 12:46:45"), 100],
                                         [Date.parse("02/05/2016 12:46:45"), 80],
                                         [Date.parse("02/04/2016 12:46:45"), 50],
                                         [Date.parse("02/03/2016 12:46:45"), 120],
                                          [Date.parse("02/02/2016 12:46:45"), 90],
                                         [Date.parse("02/01/2016 12:46:45"), 110]

    ];


   var valuesfirst = [];
   var numericchartdata = [];

    valuesfirst.push(values);
    numericchartdata.push({
        'key': "Series 1", 'values': valuesfirst[0]
    });

    function Graph() {

        nv.addGraph(function () {
            var chart = nv.models.cumulativeLineChart()
                          .x(function (d) {

                              return d[0]
                          })
                          .y(function (d) {

                              return (d[1] * 100);

                          }) //adjusting, 100% is 1.00, not 100 as it is in the data
            //.color(d3.scale.category10().range())
            //.useInteractiveGuideline(false)
            ;
            //tickValues([1078030800000, 1122782400000, 1167541200000, 1251691200000])
            chart.xAxis.tickFormat(function (d) {

                return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
            });

            chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.1%'));

            d3.select("#chart" + ' svg').datum(numericchartdata).call(chart);

            //TODO: Figure out a good way to do this automatically
            nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

            return chart;
        });    
    }
</script>
```

Comment: looks good to me, what's the problem?

Comment: are you asking how to convert the data into a cumulative sum? in this case take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477177/creating-an-array-of-cumulative-sum-in-javascript

Comment: Hi @maxymoo i am sharing a screen shot please refer it for requirements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope it would work.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link data-require="nvd3@1.1.14-beta" data-semver="1.1.14-beta" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.1.14-beta/nv.d3.css" />
<script data-require="d3@3.3.11" data-semver="3.3.11" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.3.11/d3.js"></script>
<script data-require="nvd3@1.1.14-beta" data-semver="1.1.14-beta" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.1.14-beta/nv.d3.js"></script>
 <script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<style>   

    .nv-point {
        stroke-opacity: 1 !important;
        stroke-width: 10px;
        fill-opacity: 1 !important;
    }
    .bullet { font: 10px sans-serif; }
.bullet .marker { stroke: #000; stroke-width: 2px; }
.bullet .tick line { stroke: #666; stroke-width: .5px; }
.bullet .range.s0 { fill: #eee; }
.bullet .range.s1 { fill: #ddd; }
.bullet .range.s2 { fill: #ccc; }
.bullet .measure.s0 { fill: steelblue; }
.bullet .title { font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold; }
.bullet .subtitle { fill: #999; }
</style>   
<body> <div id="chart" style="height:500px"> 
<svg height="600" width="600"></svg>  </div>   
<script>    
 var data1 = [
  {
  "key": "Blood Sugar Random",
  "values": [
   [1399787880000, 4900],
   [1418291820000, 5400],
   [1427251500000, 5200],
   [1447046040000, 4900],
   [1447669500000, 35300],
   [1448085600000, 6400],
   [1448504100000, 2800],
   [1450418400000, 5800],
   [1452229200000, 4800],
   [1454559095000, 5000],
   [1468195946000, 5400],
   [1481531373000, 5100]] }];    
      nv.addGraph(function () {

          var chart = nv.models.lineChart().interpolate('cardinal')

            .x(function (d) {
                return d[0];
            })
            .y(function (d) {
                return d[1]
            })  
            .color(d3.scale.category10().range())
            .transitionDuration(300)
            .showLegend(true)
            .showYAxis(true)
            .forceY([50, 500])
            .tooltipContent(
            function (key, x, y, e) {   

            return '<div id="tooltipcustom">' + '<p id="head">' + key + '</p>'
            + '<p>' + y + ' at ' + new Date(e.point[0]).getDate().toString() + '-' + (new Date(e.point[0]).getMonth() + 1).toString() +
                '-' + new Date(e.point[0]).getFullYear().toString() + ' ' + new Date(e.point[0]).getHours().toString() + ':' + new Date(e.point[0]).getMinutes().toString() +
                ':' + (new Date(e.point[0]).getSeconds().toString() == '0' ? '00' : new Date(e.point[0]).getSeconds().toString()) + '</p></div>'
            });



          chart.xAxis
            .tickValues([1078030800000, 1122782400000, 1167541200000, 1251691200000])
            .tickFormat(function (d) {



                return d3.time.format("%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")(new Date(d))

            });

          chart.yAxis
            .tickFormat(function (d) {



                return d3.format('.2f')(d)

            });

          d3.select('#chart svg')
            .datum(data1)
            .call(chart);

          nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

          return chart;

      }, function (chart) {


          x = chart;

          var x1 = chart.xScale()(1122782400000);
          var x2 = chart.xScale()(1251691200000);
          var height = chart.yAxis.range()[0];



          var y2 = chart.yScale()(80);
          var y1 = chart.yScale()(120);
          var width = chart.xAxis.range()[1];

          d3.select('.nv-wrap')
            .append('rect')
            .attr('y', y1)
            .attr('height', y2 - y1)
            .style('fill', '#2b8811')
            .style('opacity', 0.2)
            .attr('x', 0)
            .attr('width', width);

      });
```

Comment: This answer should include an explanation of the technique  being employed and what was wrong with the original poster's code. Answering with just an undocumented code snippet is very unhelpful for future questioners.