# Change date format to string d3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph

I'm trying to change the label format from date to string.

I tried changing the formats but it didn't work. Here is my codepen: https://codepen.io/sampath-PerOxide/pen/bzVOoG

```
var dateformat = "%Y-%m"
drawTimeSeriesGraph(data1, dateformat);
```

I want to pass the string in the place of the date.

Comment: What do you want the date to look like?

Comment: I want to change the date format to string so that I can pass any custom string like Jan-19-week1, April-19-week4...

Comment: How do you know that it is week 1?

Comment: refer this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40239174/d3-cumulative-line-chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format your axis ticks however you like with [`tickFormat`](https://github.com/d3/d3-axis#axis_tickFormat). Just pass it your own function that returns the string you want based on the data (the function can access the current **d**atum and **i**ndex).

```
xAxis.tickFormat((d, i) => {
    const date = formatDate(d)
    return `${date} - Month ${i+1}`
});
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/k-sav/pen/KJVdwB)