# How to make a list of partial sums using forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, foreach

I have an array of arrays which looks like this:

```
changes = [ [1, 1, 1, -1], [1, -1, -1], [1, 1] ];
```

I want to get the next value in the array by adding the last value

```
values = [ [1, 2, 3, 2], [1, 0, -1], [1, 2] ];
```

so far I have tried to use a forEach:

```
changes.forEach(change => {
    let i = changes.indexOf(change);
    let newValue = change[i] + change[i + 1]
});
```

I think I am on the right lines but I cannot get this approach to work, or maybe there is a better way to do it.

Comment: Please elaborate this "I want to be able to increment the values based on the next value in the array to get this result:"

Comment: I want to add the numbers in the array that are next to each other together to make the next number in the array

Comment: This is just a [cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477177/creating-an-array-of-cumulative-sum-in-javascript) wrapped in `.map`. The [answer by Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55259153/7126740) is better than anything you'll find there though.

Comment: @JollyJoker Thomas simulate `.reduce` method, why not use [.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) directly ?

Comment: @R3tep You may technically be right, but I think Thomas' version ends up easier to read.

Comment: @R3tep because I don't. Array#reduce accumulates/folds an array into a single value; Array#map maps one result-value for each item in the input array. I do both. I create one result for each item in the input while dragging along the accumulated sum.

Comment: @Thomas Look my answer, you can use an array as accumulator.

Comment: Never use `forEach` if you want to produce a result.

Comment: I think this can be done with reduce.

Answer (score 36):

You could save a sum and add the values.

```js
var array = [[1, 1, 1, -1], [1, -1, -1], [1, 1]],
    result = array.map(a => a.map((s => v => s += v)(0)));

console.log(result);
```

By using `forEach`, you need to take the object reference and the previous value or zero.

```js
var array = [[1, 1, 1, -1], [1, -1, -1], [1, 1]];

array.forEach(a => a.forEach((v, i, a) => a[i] = (a[i - 1] || 0) + v));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: That first approach looks nice, but is **really** inefficient.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder could you explain or point me in the right direction, why the first approach is inefficient?

Comment: @Thomas - Look at all the functions it's creating and executing. [Your solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55259153/157247) is great -- as concise (*way* more so than mine) and still efficient.

Comment: really, for three items in the outer array? if you really want to speed up the execution, you never use some array methods, instead use nested `for` loops and create new arrays.

Comment: @NinaScholz - We don't know what context it's meant to be used in. But hey, lots of different ways to approach a problem are good.

Comment: each inner array is the y axis of a graph, for context.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477177/creating-an-array-of-cumulative-sum-in-javascript) could use an answer like the first one

Answer (score 14):

A version with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const changes = [
  [1, 1, 1, -1],
  [1, -1, -1],
  [1, 1]
];

const values = changes.map(array => {
  let acc = 0;
  return array.map(v => acc += v);
});

console.log(values);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

And this doesn't change the source Array.

Comment: Note that the array of arrays structure is just a needless complication. The question is actually about the cumulative sum of an array. I'd split out the outer mapping function into something called `cumulativeSum`

Answer (score 4):

New ESNext features of generators are nice for this.

Here I've created a simple `sumpUp` generator that you can re-use.

```js
function* sumUp(a) {
  let sum = 0;
  for (const v of a) yield sum += v;
}

const changes = [ [1, 1, 1, -1], [1, -1, -1], [1, 1] ];
const values = changes.map(a => [...sumUp(a)]);
  
console.log(values);
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function of Array

```js
const changes = [ [1, 1, 1, -1], [1, -1, -1], [1, 1] ];    
const result = changes.map((v) => v.slice(0).map((t, i, arr) => i === 0 ? t : (arr[i] += arr[i - 1])))
console.log(changes);
console.log(result);
```

### Update

Use [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to clone array. This will prevent changes to the original array.

Comment: This **modifies** the source array, which is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Yes. And `slice` will help to prevent that. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3):

```js
const changes = [ [1, 1, 1, -1], [1, -1, -1], [1, 1] ]
let values = []
changes.forEach(arr => {
  let accu = 0
  let nestedArr = []
  arr.forEach(n => {
    accu += n
    nestedArr.push(accu)
  })
  values.push(nestedArr)
})
console.log(values)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way,

You can use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return your new array with the desired results. By using [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an array as an accumulator, you can generate the subarray.

```js
var array = [[1, 1, 1, -1], [1, -1, -1], [1, 1]],
    result = array.map(a => a.reduce((ac, v, i) => {
      const lastVal = ac[i-1] || 0;
      return [...ac, lastVal + v];
    }, []));

console.log(result);

// shorter
result = array.map(a => a.reduce((ac, v, i) => [...ac, (ac[i-1] || 0) + v], []));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easier to read way that iterates over the outer list of arrays. A copy of the inner array is made to keep the initial values (like [1, 1, 1, -1]). It then iterates over each value in the copied array and adds it to each index after it in the original array.

```js
var changes = [[1, 1, 1, -1], [1, -1, -1], [1, 1]];
changes.forEach(subArray => {
    var subArrayCopy = subArray.slice();  // Create a copy of the current sub array (i.e. subArrayCopy = [1, 1, 1, -1];)
    subArrayCopy.forEach((val, index) => { // Iterate through each value in the copy
 for (var i = subArray.length - 1; i > index; i--) { // For each element from the end to the current index
            subArray[i] += val;  // Add the copy's current index value to the original array
 }
    });
})
console.log(changes);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an array of arrays, but each constituent array is independent from the next so let's tackle them individually. Let's talk about `[1, 1, 1, -1]`.

Your use of the phrase "partial sum" is very informative. The *full sum* could be implemented using `reduce`:

```js
[1, 1, 1, -1].reduce((x, y) => x + y);
// 2
```

But you want an array of partial sums. That's very similar to this usage of `reduce`, but instead of retaining only the last computed result, we retain every intermediate value too. In other languages, this is called `scan` (cf. [F#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/array.scan%5B't,'state%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D), [Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl)).

A javascript implementation of a generic `scan` would probably look a lot like `reduce`. In fact, you can implement it with `reduce`, with just a little extra work:

```js
function scan(array, callback) {
  const results = [array[0]];

  // reduce does all the heavy lifting for us, but we define a wrapper to pass to it.
  array.reduce((...args) => {
    // The wrapper forwards all those arguments to the callback, but captures the result...
    const result = callback(...args);
    // ...storing that intermediate result in our results array...
    results.push(result);
    // ...then passes it back to reduce to continue what it was doing.
    return result;
  });

  return results;
}

// scan([1, 1, 1, -1], (x, y) => x + y) -> [1, 2, 3, 2]
```

A more robust implementation would hew closer to the standard library's `reduce`, especially around initial values:

```js
function scan(array, callback, initialValue) {
  const results = [];

  const reducer = (...args) => {
    const result = callback(...args);
    results.push(result);
    return result;
  };

  if (arguments.length === 2) {
    results.push(array[0]);
    array.reduce(reducer);
  } else {
    results.push(initialValue);
    array.reduce(reducer, initialValue);
  }

  return results;
}
```

Bringing it back together, if you'd like to do this for your arrays of arrays, it would just be a `map` over `scan`:

```js
[[1, 1, 1, -1], [1, -1, -1], [1, 1]].map(a => scan(a, (x, y) => x + y));
// [[1, 2, 3, 2], [1, 0, -1], [1, 2]]
```

No copying necessary or side effects to watch out for, and you get a handy higher-order function out of it to boot!