# Why is this cumulative formula not working for my array?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of data that I need to add up cumulatively, but the data becomes something else now that it only has two decimal places. Before, it was working just fine, but some numbers had over six decimal places. Below, I have posted some JS code with the arrays as examples. How can I cumulatively add the numbers in my array without them getting messed up?

JS

```
// Cumulative code
var cumulative = (cum) => {
  var val = 0;
  return cum.map(c => val += c);
};

var cumSum = data.map(cumulative);

// The data array that is used above...
var data = [126686.27, 125910.27, 128302.27, 126702.27, 114276.27, 111852.27, 124657.00, 124657.00, 124657.00, 124657.00, 124657.00, 124657.00]

// The incorrect result from mapping it to the cumulative variable...
[0126686.27, 0126686.27125910 .27, 0126686.27125910 .27128302 .27, 0126686.27125910 .27128302 .27126702 .27, 0126686.27125910 .27128302 .27126702 .27114276 .27, 0126686.27125910 .27128302 .27126702 .27114276 .27111852 .27, 0126686.27125910 .27128302 .27126702 .27114276 .27111852 .27124657 .00, 0126686.27125910 .27128302 .27126702 .27114276 .27111852 .27124657 .00124657 .00, 0126686.27125910 .27128302 .27126702 .27114276 .27111852 .27124657 .00124657 .00124657 .00, 0126686.27125910 .27128302 .27126702 .27114276 .27111852 .27124657 .00124657 .00124657 .00124657 .00, 0126686.27125910 .27128302 .27126702 .27114276 .27111852 .27124657 .00124657 .00124657 .00124657 .00124657 .00, 0126686.27125910 .27128302 .27126702 .27114276 .27111852 .27124657 .00124657 .00124657 .00124657 .00124657 .00124657 .00]
```

Comment: Is this all of your code, I mean what is c?

Comment: I guess your example is supposed to be `cumulative(data)` ?

Comment: @Alex https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55258925/how-to-make-a-list-of-partial-sums-using-foreach/55259065#55259065

Comment: so it's the previous val? @grahamfk45c I tried to reproduce it but I ran into TypeError: cum.map is not a function

Comment: Really? That's odd. It works for me on my end. @Alex Thanks for trying though!