# How loop through array.reduce()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have array contains  300elements []; and I want to sum each [I],

```
for(var i = 0; i<300; i++){
var array2 = arr[i].reduce((prev, next) => (
return prev + next
))
}
```

it should like that array1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9..]
array2 [3,6,10...]

Comment: see: [Creating an array of cumulative sum in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477177/creating-an-array-of-cumulative-sum-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,.....]
var array2 = []
// Log to console
for(var i = 1; i<300; i++){
  var newArray = arr.slice(0, i+1).reduce((prev, next) => {
    return prev + next
   })
   array2.push(newArray)

}
console.log(array2)
```

array2 output : [3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55...]

---

In your code

this causes an error for two reasons

```
var array2 = arr[i].reduce((prev, next) => (
return prev + next
))
```

the [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method is for arrays only and `arr[i]` would output a number. Instead you were looking to use the [`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method.

And to use `return` you must use curly braces `{}` instead of `()`. Alternatively you could've done `arr.slice(0, i+1).reduce((prev, next) => prev + next)`. (see: [When should I use a return statement in ES6 arrow functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28889450/when-should-i-use-a-return-statement-in-es6-arrow-functions#:%7E:text=Arrow%20functions%20allow%20you%20to,to%20use%20the%20return%20keyword.&text=This%20should%20be%20the%20correct,expression%27s%20value%20is%20returned%20implicitly.))

Comment: Thank a lot! All day I try to do this !  In jQuery  I use simple method ```a=[]; for (I = 0; I <10; I++){ r=0; r = + r + are[I] ; a.push(r); ``` but here it does not work. Gracias. If I only could give you "this answer is useful". Happy coding!