# Chance of something to happen using integers as percentages

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

I'm working on a job system where you can mine different types of ores in a discord bot. Depending on your skill, the chances (stored in a database) to receive certain ores change. Some will have a 0% chance at certain skill levels. At Skill 1 the chances will be the following:

```
let coal_chance = 80
let copper_chance = 15
let iron_chance = 5
let gold_chance = 0
let diamond_chance = 0
let emerald_chance = 0
```

And at Skill 2 the following:

```
let coal_chance = 50
let copper_chance = 35
let iron_chance = 10
let gold_chance = 5
let diamond_chance = 0
let emerald_chance = 0
```

And so on. My question is, how can I make a chance system based on these percentages?

I tried making a system using `Math.Random()` and an if statement, but since I have to check for a different amount of values each time I would have to make one for every skill level, and if I ever wanted to set the chance of a certain ore to 0% inside the database, I would also have to change the code.

Comment: You could create an array containing cumulative percentages. And then a single random integer between 0 and 100 can give you a value that falls in one of these buckets.

Comment: @sudheeshix I know this might be a stupid question, but would you mind giving me an example of what you mean?

Comment: Create a cumulative sum like this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20477177/creating-an-array-of-cumulative-sum-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

The crude solution I came up with based on the comment of [@sudheeshix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2457113/sudheeshix):

```js
const cumulativeChances = [ 
  {c: 100, i: "coal"},
  {c: 50, i: "copper"},
  {c: 15, i: "iron"},
  {c: 5, i: "gold"},
  {c: 0, i: "emerald"},
  {c: 0, i: "diamond"}
]
const mineOre = () => {
  let rng = Math.random() * 100
  let won = 'coal'
  for (item of cumulativeChances) {
    if (item.c < rng) break
    won = item.i
  }
  return won
}

// Testing if it works as intended
const calculatedChances = {
  coal: 0,
  copper: 0,
  iron: 0,
  gold: 0,
  emerald: 0,
  diamond: 0
}
let tries = i = 10000;
while(i--) {
  let won = mineOre()
  calculatedChances[won] += (1 / tries * 100)
}
console.log(calculatedChances)
```

There is probably room for improvement, but it provides an idea. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

Convert your resource values to an array:

```
resources = ["coal", "copper", "iron", "gold", "diamond", "emerald"];
chances = [80, 15, 5, 0, 0, 0];
```

Then, generate cumulative sums of the percentages, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55261098/2457113).

```
const cumulativeSum = (sum => value => sum += value/100)(0);
cum_chances = chances.map(cumulativeSum);
```

The values are divided by 100 to get the float values as that's what `Math.random()` generates: values between 0 and 1.
With the values in `chances` mentioned above, this will make `cum_chances` with values `[0.8, 0.95, 1, 1, 1, 1]`.

Now, generate the random probability.

```
random_prob = Math.random();
```

And find the index of the first array item that where `random_prob` falls in, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21540053).

```
idx = cum_chances.findIndex(function (el) {
    return el >= random_prob;
});
resource_found = resources[idx];
```

For example, if `random_prob` is 0.93, this will give you an index of 1 and so, `resources[idx]` will give you `"copper"`.